# How to group and count by two different dates?

Tags: mysql

I have two different columns:

```
created_at          | updated_at
--------------------| -------------------
2017-03-12 14:47:20 | 2017-03-10 14:47:20
2017-03-11 12:47:20 | 2017-03-10 14:47:20
2017-03-11 10:47:20 | 2017-03-10 14:47:20
```

I want to group records by date as follows:

```
event_date | created_at | updated_at
------------------------------------
2017-03-10 |    0       |   3
2017-03-11 |    2       |   0
2017-03-12 |    1       |   0
```

Answer (score 3):

The domain for "Date" (Date is a reserved word, let's call it event_date) is a union between created_at and updated_at.

```
select created_at as event_time, 'C' as event_type
from T
union all -- the legs are disjoint
select updated_at as event_time, 'U' as event_type
from T
```

From there we can extract the date and count each type:

```
select date(event_time) as event_date
     , count(case when event_type = 'C' then 1 end) as created_at
     , count(case when event_type = 'U' then 1 end) as updated_at
from (
    select created_at as event_time, 'C' as event_type
    from T
    union all -- the legs are disjoint
    select updated_at as event_time, 'U' as event_type
    from T
) as TT
group by date(event_time)
order by date(event_time);
```

Untested, but the principle should be valid.

Comment: `count(case when event_type = 'C' then 1 end)` can be shortened to (though still cryptic) `SUM(event_type = 'C')` .